# Module not found in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

MODULE NOT FOUND ERROR
how to solve this error

I was trying to install and run the app, but npm didn't work for react

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Mridu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\Mridu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Mridu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:17:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mridu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Mridu\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Mridu\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

delete all you node_modules, your yarn.lock/package-lock. Also, make sure you are running yarn install / npm install inside the correct folder

Comment: Still got the same problem

Comment: Maybe share more details then